# Shiny 'Disconnected from server' after an hour working just fine

Tags: r, shiny

I am using [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/) and everything is working just fine with it. The specific problem I am facing right now is that after one hour (I timed it!) it shows the `'Disconnected from server'` message and stops working. I am running some queries that refresh every couple of minutes automatically using the `reactiveTimer` function and displaying the dashboard on a TV.

Don't think it will be need but [this is the public URL](https://somosf1.shinyapps.io/SomosF1/) of my shiny dashboard. It is password protected though...

Hope you guys can help me solve this issue so I don't have to manually Reload every hour the TV! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

After hours or research, it was as simple as:

`Settings > Advanced > Read Timout` set to 8 hours instead of 3600 second.

Hope this can help other people!